# What does it mean by {APP_TPL}?

Tags: php

What is the use of `{APP_TPL}` in below example? It is displaying the same code while HTML rendering. Please provide some hint only what does it mean by `{APP_TPL}` and what is the purpose of it?

```
<?php 
ob_start(); 
?> 
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Rent A Vacation Home</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
</head> 
<body> 
<p id="keyhole"><a href="http://example.com">Adventures through the keyhole</a></p> 
{APP_TPL} 
</body> 
</html> 
<?php include 'listings.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Its probably some marker that gets replaced with the body template of the corresponding site. Theres no way we could tell what exactly is happening here.

Comment: "App template"?

Comment: As above, its some token, probably used by a php or javascript templating framework. This is not an answerable question

Comment: You probably found this here https://www.webmasterworld.com/html/4457134.htm - which is part of some type of framework. Could be anything really.

Comment: I am having the same confusion. it did nothing and displayed in plain text only. I am a java developer so I didn't have much idea about it.

Comment: It certainly doesn't mean anything in either PHP or HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ob_start();` at the beginning means that the content below is not being displayed on the page right away.

Most likely what happens is that, in `listings.php`, there's a call to something like `ob_get_contents()`, which retrieves all that HTML content.

Then there must be a function that replaces the content of `{APP_TPL}` with HTML content.

From the look of it, the file you're looking at is the main template of the website, and `{APP_TPL}` is the content of each individual page.

Comment: Yes, You are correct, I was looking into main template while data gets generated at runtime. Thank you very much..